# Redirect WebView with other domain in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview

I'm trying to redirect links from another domain to the device's default browser.

For example:

- if the link is http://domain.io, stay in the WebView;
- if the link is
  http://domain.io/page, we stay in the WebView;
- and if the link is
  http://mylink.io/, we redirect the user to the default browser of the
  device and we leave the WebView.

I tried a lot of things, but I still can not make it work. I think about using `onNavigationStateChange` with Linking.

Thanks for your help.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.statusBar} />
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://example.com'}}
          renderError={() => alert('Merci de vérifier votre connexion Internet', 'Internet non disponible')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#1D3B57",
    height: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
onNavigationStateChange(e)
{
  if(e.url !== this.state.oldUrl)
  {
    // If url changed
    if(/youtube.com/.test(e.url)) // RegExp
    {
        this.refs.WEBVIEW_REF.goBack()
        Linking.canOpenURL(e.url).then(supported => {
          if (supported) return Linking.openURL(e.url)
        })
    }
    this.setState({ oldUrl: e.url })
  }
}
```

Solution 2:

Consider looking into [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6478) to expose native `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method to JS. It might be a bit complex to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, this code still does not work. The code : https://snack.expo.io/SJoFv213M